# build and compile files outside mingw main folder

Tags: c++, mingw, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I want to be able to save my files in `E:\Documents\C++` and then be able to run and compile them. My MinGW location is `E:\MinGW\bin`. Everything is saved on a USB flash drive. I am using SublimeText to run and compile these files. Everything works fine if i save the C++ files in the `E:\MinGW\bin` folder. I just want to be able to change where to save the files and build and run them. Also I am using this as my sublime-build file

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path should contain `E:\MinGW\bin` (or you should give full path for `g++`)

Comment: how do i do that? that's what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your home directory and your path for mingw.

This page shows how to set your home directory, and where to set your PATH,
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Set_the_HOME_variable_for_cmd_exe

Here is a page that tells you how to build a cpp file,
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW_for_First_Time_Users_HOWTO

If you want to use the same home location for MINGW and windows,
http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/making-home-directory-on-msys-agree-with-Windows-td22176.html

Or, you can set your home directory to your flash drive.